# Is it possible to make multi-level template inheritance in django templates?

Tags: django, inheritance, django-templates, django-inheritance, template-inheritance

I have three html-files:

- base.html
- page.html
- comment.html

in **page.html** I extend **base.html**. In **comment.html** I extend **page.html**. Will **comment.html** extend **base.html**'s blocks?

Comment: As i know , there is not multiple inheritance, its only simple or multi-level inheritance as Daniel Roseman says.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it will. Why not to try it yourself?

Comment: Plus, this sort of multi-level inheritance is *explicitly* mentioned in the docs.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can actually use as many levels of inheritance as you'd like. From The Django Book:

> One common way of using inheritance is the following three-level approach:
>
> (1) Create a base.html template that holds the main look-and-feel of your site. This is the stuff that rarely, if ever, changes.
>
> (2) Create a base_SECTION.html template for each “section” of your site. For example, base_photos.html, base_forum.html. These templates
> all extend base.html and include section-specific styles/design.
>
> (3) Create individual templates for each type of page, such as a forum page or a photo gallery. These templates extend the appropriate
> section template.

More here: http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter04.html

Comment: As of June 2022, the djangobook link is not valid anymore.